# Solving an equation with d&c method

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to calculate value of x in this equation to 4 digits after the decimal with divide and conquer method.Values of p,q,r,s,t,u are input. How to do it in?

Time limits: 1 sec

Memory limits: 64 MB

[image]

```
float results[10000];
int n = 0;
for( float step = 0; i < 1; i+=0.00001 )
{
    results[n] = callProblem( i );
}
some divide and conquer approach

float x = 0;
float diff = 1;//Startvalue
while( )
{
    result = callProblem(x);
    if( result > 0 )
    {
        x -= diff;
        diff = diff/2;
        result = callProblem(x);
    }
    else
    {
        x += diff;
        diff = diff/2;
        result = callProblem(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your attempts at writing the algorithm?

Comment: Why do you want to use this kind of binary search? Binary search requires sorted data. And the given function is not necessarily monotonic. There may also be more than one root.

Comment: @NicoSchertler When `p`, `q`, `r` and `s` are all 0, `t` is positive and `u` is negative, it definitely has two roots.

Comment: I fail to see how this problem could lend itself to divide and conquer.

Comment: @biziclop: This example has only one root in the given domain (or none). However, there are other examples with several roots (e.g. `p=1.2, q=1, r=s=t=0, u=an appropriate negative value`). I also don't see why d&c should be used.

Comment: @NicoSchertler You're right, I forgot about the domain.

Answer (score 1):

I have generalized the bisection method into an untested recursive multi-section method:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define P 1.0
#define q 2.0
#define r 3.0
#define s 1.0
#define t 5.0
#define u -6.0

//  number of sub-intervals in search interval
#define INTERVALS 10
//  accuracy limit for recursion
#define EPSILON 1.0e-4

double f(double x) {
     double y = P * exp(-x) + q*sin(x) + r*cos(x) + s*tan(x) + t*x*x + u;

     return y;
}

//  sign macro: -1 for val < 0, +1 for val > 0
#define SGN(val) ((0.0 < val) - (val < 0.0))

//  return approximate x for function(x)==0.0
//  "function" points to the function to be solved
double solve(double xMin, double xMax, double (*function)(double)) {
     double arguments[INTERVALS + 1];
     double values[INTERVALS + 1];
     int prevSign;
     int sign;

     if (fabs(xMax - xMin) < EPSILON) {
        //  interval quite tight already
        return (xMax + xMin) / 2.0;
     }

     //  split the interval into sub-intervals
     //  evaluate the function for INTERVALS+1 equidistant points
     //  across our search interval
     for (int i = 0; i <= INTERVALS; i++) {
         double x = xMin + i*((xMax - xMin) / INTERVALS);

        arguments[i] = x;
        values[i] = function(x);
     }

    //  look for adjacent intervals with opposite function value signs
    //  if f(Xi) and f(Xi+1) have different signs, the root must be
    //  between Xi and Xi+1
    prevSign = SGN(values[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i <= INTERVALS; i++) {
        sign = SGN(values[i]);

        if (sign * prevSign == -1) {
            //  different signs! There must be a solution
            //  Shrink search interval to the detected sub-interval
            double x = solve(arguments[i - 1], arguments[i], function);

            return x;
        }
        //  remember sign for next round
        prevSign = sign;
    }

    //  no solution found: return not-a-number
    return NAN;
  }

int main(unsigned argc, char **argv) {   
    clock_t started = clock();
    clock_t stopped;
    double x = solve(0.0, 1.0, &f);

    if (isnan(x)) {
        printf("\nSorry! No solution found.\n");
    } else {
        printf("\nOK! Solution found at f(%f)=%f\n", x, f(x));
    }

    stopped = clock();
    printf("\nElapsed: %gs", (stopped - started) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    //  wait for user input
    getchar();
 }
```

Comment: I test your code with some sample but program say "No solution found". inputs: 5-5-3-10-15-1 , 12-15-18-9-4-19 ,  0-0-0-0-1-1 and outputs should be :0.2879 ,0.2879 , 1.0000   (In addition this function is decreasing in 0<=x<=1 )

Comment: Try to increase the INTERVALS parameter. Look at the ´values´ array (from within the debugging session). Unless there are opposite signs, the procedure cannot find a solution.

Comment: can you tell me the algorithm of this code? i mean how this code work? can you explain your algorithm more clearly?

Comment: @sarina: I have added comments to make it clearer. Have a look!